# Como criar um widget?

Tags: java, android, widget

Tenho em mente o provider no `@xml/widget_info` o `receiver` no Manifesto o layout do widget e a classe Provider é que tenho dúvida.Do que ela precisa ter?

Answer (score 3):

Para criar uma widget no Android você precisa de:

- Um layout para a widget, i.e. um arquivo de layout comum, que estará na pasta res/layout
- Um xml descrevendo as propriedades do widget, i.e um [AppWidgetProviderInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProviderInfo.html)
- Uma classe do tipo [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) para construir a interface da widget
- Descrever a widget no seu `AndroidManifest.xml`
- E opicionalmente você pode usar uma [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) para configurar alguma coisa que você queira quando o usuario adiciona sua widget na tela principal pela primeira vez.

Eu aprendi a fazer widgets seguindo [este tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidWidgets/article.html) do Vogel, e usei este mesmo artigo como base para responder aqui para você.

E respondendo suas perguntas sobre o widget_info e o receiver, o widget_info precisa definir o layout que o widget usara, a largura e a altura do widget e a taxa de tempo em que seu widget recebera atualizações, i.e. de quanto em quanto tempo seu receiver sera chamado. usando ainda o exemplo do vogel, segue o exemplo de widget_info:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
android:minHeight="72dp"
android:minWidth="300dp"
android:updatePeriodMillis="300000" >
</appwidget-provider>
```

e sobre o `receiver`, a sua classe que extender o [AppWidgetProvider](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html) terá um metodo chamado [onUpdate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html#onUpdate%28android.content.Context,%20android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager,%20int%5B%5D%29), esse metodo sera chamado durante o intervalo que voce definiu no widget_info e nele você pode fazer atualizações na widget, como trocar uma imagem ou um texto, ou qualquer tipo de atualização que você desejar colocar na widget.

Comment: Já segui o Vogella tbm mas nada de sucesso ;/